# How to re-lock BitLocker drive? I get error: attempt rejected

Tags: windows-7, bitlocker

I can't re-lock my BitLocker encrypted drive.

When I use `C:\>manage-bde -lock q:`, I get (translated to English):

> Error: An attempt to access the requested resource was rejected.
>
> Make sure that the account on this computer has administrator rights.

My account actually has admin rights. Is it because I use Windows 7 Home Extended?

If I add `-ForceDismount`, the error is the same.

Comment: Win 7 Home has no Bitlocker, AFAIR only only Pro, Enterprise and Ultimate have Bitlocker.

Comment: @Robert Plainly, I can't _encrypt_ a drive under Windows 7 Home Extended, but I can unlock/re-lock already encrypted drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be an administrator, but did you start Command Prompt with admin rights? If you didn’t get a UAC dialog along the way, you did not.

UAC means that unless requested (either manually or by the application), software does *not* have admin rights.

A quick way that IIRC also works on Windows 7 is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to launch the program from Windows Search.